# How to rerender component after autorization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this thunk function

```
export const logout = () => {
   return (dispatch) => {
       authAPI.logout().then(response => {
           if (response.data.resultCode === 0) {
               dispatch(toggleIsAuth(false));
           }
       })
   }
}
```

and this html

```
<div className={s.login}>
                {props.resultCode !== 1
 ? <span onDoubleClick={() => props.logout()}>{props.login}</span>
 : <NavLink to="/login">Login</NavLink>}

            </div>
```

So when I double click on the span it works just fine and signs me out but I do not see Navlink. And I have to refresh the page to actually see it. Can someone help me to figure out this problem?

Comment: Can you console.log that props.resultCode actually changes to 1?

Comment: I initialaze it in `initialState` as `resultcode: 1`. And it does change. API Responses with `resultcode: 0` if everything is okay.

Comment: The api response is 0 if successful, but can you check that the props.resultCode  is actually updated. So put a console.log before {props.resultCode !== 1...} and check if that will be called correctly. For example in that render function/ body of the function component.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I solved it a bit diffrently. I added a trigger `isAuth` and toggle it with actions login and logout. It was poor decision to use to resultCode I guess.

Comment: Thats works too. Np